# how to make amChart column with 3 axis vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, amcharts

I want to create vertical clustered column chart using amChart with 3 axis.

I already made the horizontal design like this code shown below, my question is... how can i make this chart vertical?

As far as i know (googling), amChart can easily do this by [rotating the labels](https://www.amcharts.com/dataviz-tip-13-switch-horizontal-bar-chart-labels-dont-fit/). my question is... where should i put this "rotate": true ? 
i'm not familiar with javascript. Anyone can help?

any help will be very much appreciate.

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

 // Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "year": 2005,
  "income": 23.5,
  "expenses": 18.1,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2006,
  "income": 26.2,
  "expenses": 22.8,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2007,
  "income": 30.1,
  "expenses": 23.9,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2008,
  "income": 29.5,
  "expenses": 25.1,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2009,
  "income": 24.6,
  "expenses": 25,
  "cumi" : 13
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
categoryAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#";
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.1;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.9;

var  valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis()); 
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueX = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryY = "year";
  series.name = name;
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueX}[/]";
  series.columns.template.height = am4core.percent(100);
  series.sequencedInterpolation = true;

  var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  valueLabel.label.text = "{valueX}";
  valueLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "left";
  valueLabel.label.dx = 10;
  valueLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
  valueLabel.label.truncate = false;

  var categoryLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  categoryLabel.label.text = "{name}";
  categoryLabel.label.horizontalCenter = "right";
  categoryLabel.label.dx = -10;
  categoryLabel.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
  categoryLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
  categoryLabel.label.truncate = false;
}

createSeries("income", "Income");
createSeries("expenses", "Expenses");
createSeries("cumi", "Cumi");
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: The article describes what you already have as a horizontal chart, not a vertical chart, so this is kind of confusing. Are you looking to change the orientation so that the bars to go from bottom to top?

Comment: @xorspark my bad sorry, edited... can you help this out sir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to replace `chart.yAxes` for `chart.xAxes` and `chart.xAxes` for `chart.yAxes`.

Essentially `CategoryAxis` needs to go to `xAxes` and `ValueAxis` needs to go to `yAxes`.

You will also need to change `valueX` for `valueY` and `categoryY` for `categoryX`:

```js
series.dataFields.valueY = field;
series.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
```

There few other changes on the example below. I recommend you to check more about [axes in the documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/).

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

 // Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "year": 2005,
  "income": 23.5,
  "expenses": 18.1,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2006,
  "income": 26.2,
  "expenses": 22.8,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2007,
  "income": 30.1,
  "expenses": 23.9,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2008,
  "income": 29.5,
  "expenses": 25.1,
  "cumi" : 13
},{
  "year": 2009,
  "income": 24.6,
  "expenses": 25,
  "cumi" : 13
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
categoryAxis.numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#";
categoryAxis.renderer.inversed = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.1;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.9;

var  valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis()); 
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
  series.name = name;
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueX}[/]";
  series.columns.template.height = am4core.percent(100);
  series.sequencedInterpolation = true;

  var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  valueLabel.label.text = "{valueX}";
  valueLabel.label.verticalCenter = "bottom";
  valueLabel.label.dx = 10;
  valueLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
  valueLabel.label.truncate = false;

  var categoryLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  categoryLabel.label.text = "{name}";
  categoryLabel.label.verticalCenter = "top";
  categoryLabel.label.dx = -10;
  categoryLabel.label.hideOversized = false;
  categoryLabel.label.truncate = false;
  
  categoryLabel.label.rotation = -90;
}

createSeries("income", "Income");
createSeries("expenses", "Expenses");
createSeries("cumi", "Cumi");
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help sir.
ok, i will check more for amChart documentation. have a nice day :)